# WLAPP file upload failed in MobileFirst Operation Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-8, mobilefirst-server

I am trying to upload a WLAPP in MobileFirst operational console. Its failing with server error.

00000113 ServiceProxy  E   Throwable Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 107  Transport endpoint is not connected while redirecting request to https://sl.mydomain.com:9445/wladmin/management-apis/1.0/runtimes/mxcontigosales/applications?async=true

- MobileFirst Server Version: Server version: 7.1.0.00.20151114-1616
- Studio Version: 7.1.0.00.20151114-1616
- Database: DB2 10.1 WorkGroup
- WAS 8.5 Fix Pack 7 ND

I tired restarting the Node agent, Application Server. Nothing works. Getting the same error.

Comment: This sounds more related to your softlayer configuration than to MobileFirst. Does it work in a standalone server? in the development server? Also, where are the logs.

Comment: Hi Idan, Today we got the same in our PROD server. It seems intermittent. On the server, while uploading WLAPP file, I am getting only those 2 lines of the message. "Async IO operation failed"..

Comment: Found this artical, the error message is same. http://veithen.github.io/2013/05/06/websphere-jax-ws-errors.html

Comment: Am I to understand this is resolved then?

Comment: Hi Adar, I created PMR for this issue, After analysing all the logs, it's a connection reset request from my network while uploading the WLAPP file. We reached our network support team to trace the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, this at least appears to not be related to MobileFirst, as the connection reset originates from the network layer:

> Hi Adar, I created PMR for this issue, After analysing all the logs, it's a connection reset request from my network while uploading the WLAPP file. We reached our network support team to trace the same...